# Duda con patrón Singleton en Java

Tags: java, constructor

Estoy creando una ventana en java que al instanciarla recibe un dato. Específicamente un int. El problema es que al crear el Patrón Singleton cuando tengo que poner dentro de el If que Instancia es igual a una Instancia de la ventana me pide el dato que iría en la instancia, pero no puedo poner el dato porque este va en el constructor y el getter de instancia va fuera de este. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

```
      public class PedidoDetalles extends javax.swing.JFrame {

           public static PedidoDetalles instancia;

            public static PedidoDetalles getInstancia() {

                if(instancia == null){

                    instancia = new PedidoDetalles(a);
                    instancia.setVisible(true);
                }
                return instancia;
            }


            public PedidoDetalles(int a) {                                                                            

                initComponents();
            }
   }
```

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado, gracias por el consejo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `getInstancia()` puede recibir el valor que necesitas para ser usado dentro de la clase Singleton :

```
     public class PedidoDetalles extends javax.swing.JFrame {

               public static PedidoDetalles instancia = null;
               private int a;

               public static PedidoDetalles getInstancia(int a) {

                    if(instancia == null){        
                        instancia = new PedidoDetalles();
                        instancia.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    return instancia;
                }


            public PedidoDetalles() {                                                                            
                initComponents();
            }
   }
```

Llamando el método de esta forma:

```
 ClassicSingleton.getInstancia(12);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Funciona perfecto.

Comment: Excelente Joel!, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a hacer un constructor sin parámetros con un valor por defecto para la variable para actualizarla posteriormente.

Comment: Si ya había pensado en eso. Pero la idea era que desde que se instancia y se hace visible la ventana estuvieran los valores. Lo solucione poniéndole el mismo parámetro al getter.